# Plot shapely polygon on top of rasterio

Tags: geopandas, shapely, rasterio, matplotlib

I have 2D raster and I'm interested in plotting on top of it polygon.
When I print the geometry and its' type I get this:

```
#this is inside a loop that takes each time one row which is one polygon
    for geom,ids in zip(tmp[col_geometry],tmp[col_plots]):
        print('geometry:{},type:{}'.format(geom,type(geom)))
....


geometry:POLYGON ((-53.770698 -12.17007, -53.770694 -12.17005, -53.770695 -12.17006, -53.770698 -12.17007)),type:<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

However, when I tried to plot this polygon on top of rasterio ,I received error:

```
            img=rasterio.open(tiff)
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
            rasterio.plot.show(img,transform=img.transform,ax=ax,cmap='Spectral')
#plot all the polygons I have from the geopandas shapefile:
            tmp.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')
#plot the specific one polygon that was selected in this iteration:
            geom.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='green')
            plt.show()
```

the error:

> AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'plot'

How can I plot this geometry on top of the raster (that has already the geopandas dataframe plot on it) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your existing Shapely Polygon geometry "geometry:POLYGON ((-53.770698 -12.17007, -53.770694 -12.17005, -53.770695 -12.17006, -53.770698 -12.17007)),type:<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>" you can use the following:

Replace your below line:

```
geom.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='green')
```

With this one:

```
xs, ys = geom.exterior.xy
ax.fill(xs, ys, alpha=0.5, fc='r', ec='none')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to "bypass" this issue , by converting the polygon into geoseries,and then plot it.
However, if there is any smarter ways I would love to learn.

```
 g = GeoSeries([geom])
...
 g.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='cyan',linewidth=3)
```